# Problems installing a Samsung CLP325 Colour Laser printer under Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

I have (unsuccessfully) tried to get my Samsung CLP325 colour laser printer to work under Ubuntu 13.10.

The best I seem to achieve is in Black and White mode - but this is unacceptable.

Has anyone managed to install and use the full facilities of this printer ?
If so, could you please let me know how you did it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a printer in the same line, the CLX-2160n

I prefer these drivers, as they don't over-use the toner like the default drivers in Ubuntu, probably due to the extra colour profiles.

http://foo2qpdl.rkkda.com/

You may have to visit the printer options and select color rather than monochrome.